# Find bytes from an offset

Tags: c#

So I have this:

```
public static long FindPosition(Stream stream, byte[] byteSequence)
{
     if (byteSequence.Length > stream.Length)
         return -1;

     byte[] buffer = new byte[byteSequence.Length];

     using (BufferedStream bufStream = new BufferedStream(stream, byteSequence.Length))
     {
           int i;
           while ((i = bufStream.Read(buffer, 0, byteSequence.Length)) == byteSequence.Length)
           {
                if (byteSequence.SequenceEqual(buffer))
                    return bufStream.Position - byteSequence.Length;
                else
                    bufStream.Position -= byteSequence.Length - PadLeftSequence(buffer, byteSequence);
           }                 
     }
     return  -1;
}
private static int PadLeftSequence(byte[] bytes, byte[] seqBytes)
{
     int i = 1;
     while (i < bytes.Length)
     {
          int n = bytes.Length - i;
          byte[] aux1 = new byte[n];
          byte[] aux2 = new byte[n];
          Array.Copy(bytes, i, aux1, 0, n);
          Array.Copy(seqBytes, aux2, n);
          if (aux1.SequenceEqual(aux2))
             return i;
             i++;
      }
      return i;
}
```

Which works perfectly to get an offset that has a specific set of bytes, but now I want to do the inverse, find a set of bytes from a specific offset.
How can I do that?

Comment: Seek or read to the offset first? Perhaps create an example input and output of what you want to do, it's a bit unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry I'm a big noob in this matter, I found that code and worked for what I wanted, I didn't write it myself. Could you share an example of seek or read? Maybe take offset 0x763AFC as an example? I know I'm being lazy but I already tried lots of ways I found here on stackoverflow and haven't been able to make it work :/ Edit: Would be something like get byte[] {0xXX, 0xYY, 0xZZ, 0xXY, 0xYX} from offset 0x00763AFC

Comment: `byte[] ReadBytes(Stream stream, long offset, long bytesCount)` this is what you need? Read specific bytes count from specific offset?

Comment: Yes that's what I need, I don't see a ReadBytes method anywhere though, what class does it belong to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

```
long offset = 100L; // Offset
int bytesCount = 20; // Number of bytes to read
byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesCount];

stream.Seek( offset, SeekOrigin.Begin ); // Set offset from Begin of a stream
stream.Read( buffer, 0, bytesCount ); // Read bytesCount from previous set offset
```

More detail about [Seek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @user1913644 You're welcome)) Mark this answer if it is correct.