# Converting a memory stream to an array but taking only a specified number of elements

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I'm interested in implementing image format validation.
I'm taking an input file (as IFormFile), and I want to encode it to bytes, and to compare these bytes to the starting bytes of formats such as jpeg and png. If the file's first two bytes equal to those of jpeg, for example, then the file is a jpeg image.

The implementation attached converts the entire file to an array of bytes, which seems to be inefficient:

```
        using var stream = new MemoryStream();
        file.CopyTo(stream);
        byte[] checkIfImage = stream.ToArray();
```

Then, we'll compare it to bytes of jpeg or png.

```
        var png = new byte[] { 137, 80 };
        var jpeg = new byte[] { 255, 216 };
```

Rather than creating this big inefficient array containing all of the file's bytes, I want to create an array containing only the first two bytes, so the comparison will be efficient.
However, I cannot simply add `.Take(2)` or something like that after `.ToArray()`.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45605748/find-bytes-from-an-offset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [stream.Read method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=net-5.0)

```
var firstBytes = new byte[2];
var nrBytesRead = filestream.Read(firstBytes);
if(nrBytesRead == firstBytes.Length){
    // do the comparison
}
```

Classes like [binaryreader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader?view=net-5.0) might also be useful. Reading the entire stream to memory can be convenient, but should in general be avoided if performance or memory usage is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding any other problems you have conceptually or otherwise... Since you are *allocating* for the `MemoryStream`, you might as well just use [`GetBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer?view=net-5.0) to access to the underlying array. From there you can use any comparison technique you like.

In this example i'm using `Memory<T>` and `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` and using  `SequenceEqual` to check for the pattern (`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`)

**Given**

```
private static readonly (string Name, ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Pattern)[] _patterns =
{
   ("png", new byte[] {1, 2}),
   ("jpj", new byte[] {1, 216}),
};
```

**Usage**

```
using var file = new MemoryStream(new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
using var stream = new MemoryStream();
file.CopyTo(stream);

var mem = stream.GetBuffer().AsMemory();

foreach (var (name, pattern) in _patterns) 
   if (pattern.Span.SequenceEqual(mem.Span(0,pattern.Span.Length)))
      Console.WriteLine("Found : " + name + ", " + Convert.ToHexString(pattern.Span));
```

**Output**

```
Found : png, 0102
```

<sub>***Disclaimer 1** : If you are using the old and busted .net framework, all bets are off. You will need to do this with arrays and crayons*</sub>

<sub>***Disclaimer 2** : This was not meant to be the greatest code in the world, it was just a tribute*</sub>

Comment: I know how to carry out the comparison. What I'm interested in is creating an array that contains the file's first two bytes ONLY, not all of its bytes. By applying the GetBuffer(), I was only able to get all the bytes. How can I get only the first two bytes? I'm trying to process images from a POST request. encoding all the bytes for a GIF for example takes lots of time, that's why I'm interested in taking only its first 2 bytes and compare it to the GIF format......

Comment: @TommyTom whether you like it or not, the code you had is already allocating with memory stream.  GetBuffer and the rest of the code is basically 0 cost and 0 allocations

Comment: @TommyTom if you are trying to not load anything at all into memory (including the memory stream you had in your code), then you need to give the rest of your code that saves that filestream somewhere, so a low allocation variant (which doesn't include the memory stream in your original code) can be tendered